# Как вывести версию TCP-сервера в сокет TCP-клиента?

Tags: c++, linux, c, сокет, tcp

Не могу понять, как вывести версию TCP-сервера в сокет TCP-клиента. Кто нибудь знает?

Comment: а что то другое можете вывести? например, "hello client"?

Comment: Да ,могу вывести

Comment: Послать через соединение как самые обычные данные. При необходимости как то помеченную, согласно протокола обмена, что это именно версия а не что то другое.

Comment: так просто пошлите в вывод "1.0" и все готово

Comment: не следует создавать новый аккаунт для каждого вопроса...

Comment: так минусят все акки)

Answer (score -3):

Ответ от Mike:

Послать через соединение как самые обычные данные. При необходимости как то помеченную, согласно протокола обмена, что это именно версия а не что то другое.